# SQL Query for multiple tables including 2 'many to many' table

Tags: sql-server

```
query2 = "SELECT k.key_tag, k.key_avail 
          FROM keyinfo k 
          JOIN keyingroup kig ON k.key_id = kig.key_id 
          WHERE kig.group_id = (
             SELECT uig.group_id 
             FROM useringroup uig 
             JOIN users u ON uig.user_id = u.user_id 
             WHERE u.user_csn = '" & GV.userCSN & "')"
```

keyingroup table

[image]

useringroup table

[image: https://i.imgur.com/1ZCPQOk.png]

Other than the 2 tables shown in the images, there is a keyinfo table, a accessgroup table and a users table. The idea here is that the 2 images is made as a 'many to many' relation table. Where in the table in image 1 is to show that a key can be accessed by multiple access groups while in the second image users can have multiple access groups and as long as a key falls within that access group, the user has permission to draw/loan it. The SQL statement above is what I have right now but it is not returning any rows at all and I have no idea if the way I'm querying is even right. Can someone provide some pointers as to what could be wrong and what I should have done?

Comment: Select your two statements and match them to see what they got. Then its easier.  And what is " & ? are you using some kinda C# application ?

Comment: This can only be solved if you post sample data and sample expected output. For example, what is in `keyinfo`, the very first table in your SQL?

Comment: @Thomas Okay I'll give that a try. Also I'm using VB.NET.

Comment: If you post the result from the first SQL Select and post the results from your subselect (in your where clause) then it easier too see why you dont get results.

Comment: @Thomas The result i got from the second SQL Select was 1,3,5 which was the intended result and when I hardcoded a value of 1 for the first SQL Select statement    WHERE kig.group_id = '1'    it does return a valid result as well. Is there a reason why it does not return a result when both statements are combined?

Comment: 'The result i got from the second SQL Select was 1,3,5 ' in that case your SQL is wrong for it, you are using the '=' operator to ask if there is equality between multiple values, but you possibly need to use IN - are you actually getting a runtime error?  It is not right to say WHERE X = (1,2,3), the second query would have to return only a single value.  You can have WHERE X IN (1,2,3) with the (1,2,3) being the results of a sub-query

Comment: As @Cato writes. Try to use where kig.group_id IN (select xxxxxx

Comment: Yes thank you using IN solved the problem. How do I set this post to answered?

Comment: _You should take care to understand the real problem here!_ The real problem is most likely that you had an error handler in your application code that was absorbing the error that you got from your incorrect SQL statement.